# how to populate csv into textarea value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, csv

I'd like to populate the value of a textarea input with a csv string. Here's my csv string (it's in a rails view at this variable @item[:template]):

```
x,y,series,size
2,-0.083014839,Group 0,0.883928284
-9,0.355697349,Group 0,0.149154477
5,-0.256459661,Group 0,0.066308001
3,-0.243723214,Group 0,0.388138931
7,-0.663022927,Group 0,0.09761712
0,-0.587616252,Group 0,0.246573359
```

Here's my textarea tag in rails:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'template', nil, class: 'form-control temp-grab',
          value: @item[:template] %>
```

The textarea isn't actually populating though. I don't know if it's because it's a multiline string or because the characters aren't escaped. I've tried simple_format(@item[:template]) but it isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag), any parameter other than `size`, `rows`, `cols`, `disabled`, and `escape` becomes HTML attributes. HTML `textarea`s do not have a `value` attribute. You instead want to do this:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'template', @item[:template], class: 'form-control temp-grab' %>
```